# How to set the GOP size on VC-1 encoder in Media Foundation?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to set the GOP size (number of frames) and set the "closed GOP" flag on VC-1 encoder (`WMVideo9 Encoder MFT`) in Media Foundation, but I don't see a way to do it. M$ created a thousands of interfaces, but most of them are useless.
(I even tried using async codecs that apparently can benefit from the GPU, etc... LOL, what a joke that is...)

Back to the problem...
For example, there is an `IWMCodecProps` interface exposed by the `IMFTransform`, but it's read only. There are tons of attributes accessible through the `IMFAttributes`, but I don't see one for setting the GOP size and closing the GOP.

Is it possible at all? Looks like M$ is pushing away everybody coding for money. Media foundation is good for playing around only....

P.S.
Not being able to answer is not the the reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`ICodecAPI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd311953%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. It exposes a lot of settings for video encoding. You would also want have a look at following `ICodecAPI` properties.

- [CODECAPI_AVEncMPVGOPSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [CODECAPI_AVEncMPVGOPOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [CODECAPI_AVEncMPVGOPSInSeq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Setting CODECAPI_AVEncMPVGOPSize on Intel hardware has no effect. It works fine on Nvidia hardware MFT though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051443/intel-h264-hardware-mft-poor-performance-compared-to-nvidia

Answer (score 0):

GOP size analog for VC-1 encoder, which is [Windows Media Video 9 Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows Media Video 9 Advanced Profile mode, is [`MFPKEY_KEYDIST` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> Specifies the maximum time, in milliseconds, between key frames in the codec output.

Compare to [GOP size](http://documentation.apple.com/en/compressor/usermanual/index.html#chapter=18%26section=5%26tasks=true) coming from MPEG-2, which number of frames between neighboring I-frames.

Comment: Is there a similar property available in Mediafoundation MFTs? I’m looking for an option to control the time or number of frames between each I frame, I have had not luck yet.